# Getting localized language in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I am displaying and determining the selected language in my website by using URLs in this format :

```
/{languageCode}/Area/Controller/Action
```

And in my C# when I need to find the language Code I am using this syntax :

```
RouteData.Values["languageCode"]
```

However, when I need to call an action using JQuery, how do I determine the language code so that I can call the correct route i.e. `en-US/Area/Controller/Action` ?  I don't know how to access this information in my client side Javascript.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your URL has the language code. How about using

```
window.location
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

And then extract the language from the url. Maybe something like:

```
var url = "example.com/en-us/Area/Controller/Action"; //or window.location:
var lang = url.split("/")[1];
```

No need to use JQuery! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could emit it, server-side, e.g.:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", routeValues)';
```